# Javascript Map dereference

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory, reference

If I have a map containing the `id`s of DOM elements and I want to de-reference an entry in the map, so the corresponding element can be picked up by garbage collector, what are the steps I should go through to make sure there is no memory leak? Should I `delete` or `= null` on the map entry? What do I need to do about the element itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I assume by "map" you mean "object".)*

To permanently remove a property and value from an object, use `delete`. Using `null` will have the  effect of clearing the value, but retaining the property.

Both will allow the value to be garbage collected.

But to what you're trying to accomplish, if the map only has reference to an ID string, it will have no impact on the element itself. You need to drop all references to the element *(in DOM and JavaScript)* to ensure the element  is garbage collected.

Comment: I guess it's because I was using the mapped ids to get the element elsewhere, in which case a reference would have been made.

Comment: @JasonHu: JavaScript doesn't have pointers, and its passing/assignment is always "by value", so when you used the IDs in the map to get the element, a copy of the ID string was used, so no reference is retained. That said, JavaScript implementations do implement strings as reference types so that the entire string doesn't need to be copied. But unless you've retained some permanent reference to that string, it'll be collected.